# li click events on Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari, onclick, html-lists

This issue is specifically with Safari.

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li onclick="do_something();"><!-- block with stuff in it --></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the above is loaded normally, the onclick applies to the entire li block. The problem is, later on when I use ajax to populate the #list div dynamically...

```
$("#list").html('<ul><li onclick="do_something();"><!-- block with stuff in it --></li></ul>');
```

The click event doesn't fire on the entire block but only the part of the block (i.e. the part of the block where content does not exist, the background).

Answer (score 2):

That's strange. You can use jquery events for this though:

```
$("#list")
    .empty()
    .append ( $('<ul><li><!-- block with stuff in it --></li></ul>' )
        .find('li')
        .click(dosomething)
        .end()
    );
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be solving the problem (the li is only clickable for a small portion, not the entire block). But it does make for a rather interesting way to populate the div. :P

Comment: Might be some CSS. Do you have the page online?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use, for weird security reasons, onclick while using innerHTML property (which is exactly what html() does). You need to attach events using addEvent(mootools) -> find some relevant method in jquery

Comment: Can you specify? When using ajax, the onclick seems to be working, but only for a portion of the <li> and not the entire block (because the block has other divs in it). This contrasts with when the page is loaded normally, the onclick fires on the entire block.